# JavaScript Regular Expression digits not matching string containing single zero

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm using the JavaScript regular expression:

```
val.match(/\d*$/)
```

It works as expected for all numbers expect when the string is "0". A single zero value does not match. How do I include that?

Test case:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" id="txtRange" />
<div id="result" />

<script type="text/javascript">


    var rangeValidate = function (val, min, max) {
        if (val == "") {
            return "You must specify a number between " + min + " and " + max;
        } else if (val.match(/\d*$/) == false) {
            return "You must specify a number between " + min + " and " + max;
        } else if ((val < min) || (val > max)) {
            return "You must specify a number between " + min + " and " + max;
        } else {
            return "";
        }

        return "You must specify a number between " + min + " and " + max;
    }

    $('#txtRange').bind('change', function(){
            var value = $('#txtRange').val();
            var resultText = rangeValidate(value, 0, 8);
            $('#result').html(resultText);
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It matches, `"0".match(/\d*$/)` returns the array `["0"]` which when used in comparison is converted to its string representation `"0"`.

<del>But in JavaScript,  the string `"0"` is "falsy", meaning it evaluates to `false` in a boolean context.</del>

*Edit:* Ok, the string is not "falsy". Still, there is some conversion going on which eventually has the effect that `"0" == false` evaluates to `true`.

You should use [`.test()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) (which always returns a boolean value) instead and/or strict equality `===`:

```
} else if (/\d*$/.test(val) === false) {
```

If the whole string should be a number, you should also anchor the expression at the beginning of the string:

```
/^\d*$/
```

Or don't use regex at all and use `+` to convert the value to a number. If it cannot be converted (because it contains something else than digits) it will return the special value `NaN` (not a number). You're code would become:

```
var rangeValidate = function (val, min, max) {
    val = +val;
    if (isNaN(val) || (val < min) || (val > max)) {
        return "You must specify a number between " + min + " and " + max;
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

See a [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wABHS/).

Comment: @Felix King - the string "0" is definitely **not** "falsy" in JavaScript. It's a non-empty string, and it is therefore `true`.

Comment: @Pointy: At least in the Chrome console, typing `"0" == false` gives me `true`. How should I interpret that? Ah I see.... there is some more conversion going on.

Comment: try `!!"0"` instead, or `if ("0") alert('falsy');`

Comment: @Pointy: Yep, I tried it and you are right. My apologies. Fixed my answer regarding this.

Comment: @Felix King - I found it in the ES5 standard. When the types around an "==" comparison are not the same, and one is a boolean, then the boolean is promoted to a number first. That, in turn, causes the string to be converted to a number, and so the actual comparison is between the numeric 0 obtained from the boolean conversion and the numeric 0 obtained from parsing the string.

Comment: Oh and that's section 11.9.3, if you're curious and bored :-)

Comment: @Pointy: Thanks, I remember vaguely that I read this somewhere... I will have a look again :)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, wow... just weird.  What's actually going on:

The result from a .match is an array.  Since you have a single match, your result is ['0'], and ['0'].toString() === '0' == false.

In ANY other case (if you matched a paren set in the regex, etc), this would be NOT equal false regardless of whether or not it was zero.

Now for the weird bit:

```
> ['0'] == false
true
> !!['0']
true
```

So the == operator forces an implicit .toString() where as the ! operator doesn't!

Answer (score 1):

`0 == false` returns true in javascript.
`0 === false` will return false in javascript.

Change your `val.match(/\d*$/) == false` in `val.match(/\d*$/) === false`. I don't know if this will fix your problem, but it's always good to keep this in mind.

Comment: It actually doesn't, FYI. `=== false` will ALWAYS be false since the result of .match is an array.  and `[] === false` will never match.  Apparently, however, `==` has an implicit `.toString()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
var rangeValidate = function (val, min, max) {
    if ( /^\d+$/.test(val) && val>=min && val<=max ) {
        return "";
    } else {
        return "You must specify a number between " + min + " and " + max;
    }
}
```